# Read JSON in Javascript with no key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hello I have a PHP script that returns this json (using the json_encode() function) :

```
["cruiser","SF","Car"]
```

I'm using AJAX to receive the response

How can I print or access in javascript the first element of this json?

Thanks

Comment: how are you receiving it client side? with `$.ajax`? OR more to the point, how do you normally read your JSON data? This is no different. The key for the first element is 0

Comment: @OussamaLord if the the 0 index is a "[", it means that your JSON is is a String "[\"cruiser\",\"SF\",\"Car\"]". String, as an array of characters would cause the 0 index to return the first character, "["

Comment: so how can I read the fisrt element if it's a string?

Comment: a sample success handler for `$.ajax` would look like this then `function(data){alert(data[0]);}` put that in your ajax request as the success handler function

Comment: data[0] this return "[" I said that.

Comment: add `dataType:"json"` to your $.ajax request

Comment: or you can do $.parseJSON(data)[0]

Comment: By adding dataType:"json" it's working well now Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 4):

Its not `Json` its an `array`, you could access its first value by,

```
var x = ["cruiser","SF","Car"];
alert(x[0]);
```

Please read over here to know [what is JSON?](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: If it is the contents of a string, then yes it is JSON

Comment: Technically it's valid JSON. What he means is that it's an Array rather than Plain Object.

Comment: @Tim I just seen that the square brackets are not covered with quotes. :)

Comment: The OP says though that it is the output of `json_encode`. Maybe you should read.

Comment: @cbayram But OP misunderstood that the snippet was a JSON with out keys right.? At that context, I guess this answer would help him to know a bit about JSON. :)